# Meaning of "size_t cnt" in library prototype

Tags: sizeof, size-t

Given the prototype:
unsigned int NI488CC ibwrt    (int ud, const void * buf, size_t cnt);

What is "6L" in the function call:
ibwrt(Dev, "*IDN?\n", 6L);

Have I forgotten some very basic C stuff?

Comment: A number of type `long`.

Answer (score 0):

`L` stands for 'long' literal value. See [integer-literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal):

> `integer-suffix`, if provided, may contain one or both of the following (if both are provided, they may appear in any order:
>
> - unsigned-suffix (the character u or the character U)
> - long-suffix (the character l or the character L) or the long-long-suffix (the character sequence ll or the character sequence LL) (since C++11)

Comment: and why use such literal qualifier rather than just the constant "6"?

Answer (score 0):

`std::size_t` is the unsigned integer type of the result of the `sizeof` operator.
Although the type is guaranteed to be unsigned, it is still implementation defined.

Using `l` or `L` is an integer literal for long.

For example.  In the following code:

```
auto x = 6L;  
auto y = 6;
```

`x` will be of type long while y will be of type `y`.

Using `L` when passing a `std::size_t` is not required.
Due to Integral promotion and the unlikelyhood of competing function overloads, passing `6L` is superfluous.  Passing `6` would suffice.